# Fact or Myth, Will too much smile cause wrinkles?

Tags: dermatology, smile-smiling

I wonder many people say  "If too much smile can be wrinkles on the face?" From some **articles**, I found some opinions that is the smile can be wrinkles on the face. But on the other hand is not it if we smile it means we are happy ? and is not it if we smile can make us stay young?

Comment: Buddhist monks are said to have the least wrinkled and best skin as they age, in part because of the modulation of expression of emotion on their faces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrinkles are not directly proportional to age; people have different collagen properties.  Some people wrinkle far earlier than others, and in different ways.

But yes, [smiling does promote wrinkles to some degree](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/wrinkles/symptoms-causes/dxc-20265774) due to repeated muscular contractions causing the same skin wrinkling pattern, but smiling also has [beneficial](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/cutting-edge-leadership/201206/there-s-magic-in-your-smile) and lasting [neurobiological effects](http://www.neuropsychotherapist.com/the-neuroscience-of-smiling-and-laughter/) that go far beyond the minimal superficial impact of slightly deeper wrinkles.

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: That now almost begs the question: How good are ordinary people at detecting smile induced wrinkles in neutral still pictures? (Wrong SE for that, alas I know.)